# Simple attempt to get json data into an array

Tags: arrays, json, angular, mapping, angular-httpclient

I have the data being printed out to a log . Have do I simply put this in an array? So I can do

```
   <ul *ngIf="courses$ | async as courses else noData">
                <li *ngFor="let course of courses">
                    {{course.name}}
                </li>
            </ul>
            <ng-template #noData>No Data Available</ng-template>




export class SurveyComponent {

surveys: Survey[];
survey: Survey;

constructor(private http: HttpClient) {

}

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.http.get('http://localhost:54653/api/survey/').subscribe(data => {
          console.log(data);
    },
        err => {
            console.log('Error occured.');
        }
    );
}
```

}

```
export class Survey {
constructor(id?: string, name?: string, description?: string) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.description = description;
}

public id: string;
public name: string;
public description: string;
```

}

[image: snip]

EDIT 1: Why does the first .map work and the other doesn't ?

[image]

Comment: try this.http.get<Survey[]>('http://localhost:54653/api/survey/').subscribe ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this ?

```
surveys$: Observable<Survey[]>;

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.surveys$ = this.http.get<Survey[]>('http://localhost:54653/api/survey/');
}
```

Comment: TS2322: Type 'Observable<Object>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<Survey[]>'.
  Type 'Object' is not assignable to type 'Survey[]'.
    The 'Object' type is assignable to very few other types. Did you mean to use the 'any' type instead?
      Property 'find' is missing in type 'Object'

Comment: @punkouter with the httpClient you must specify the type returned from the http request, or it will assume `Object` (the type mismatch error you are seeing). so your get should be `this.http.get<Survey[]>(...)` or if you do not want to strictly type it `this.http.get<any>(...)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use rxjs `map` operator after your API call:

```
...
courses$: Observable<Survey[]>
...
ngOnInit(): void {
  // if you want use the async pipe in the view, assign the observable
  // to your property and remove .subscribe

  this.courses$ = this.http
     .get('http://localhost:54653/api/survey/')
     .map(surveys => 
        surveys.map(survey => new Survey(survey.id, survey.name, survey.description))
     )
}
...
```

Comment: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error TS2339 (TS) Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Object'. QuickApp (tsconfig project) C:\Users\Matt_Herb\Downloads\IbewSurveyQa\QuickApp\QuickApp\ClientApp\app\components\survey\survey.component.ts 55 Active

Comment: I have import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

Comment: @punkouter do you have import map too? - import "rxjs/add/operator/map"

Comment: import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

Comment: @punkouter I see, it's strange because you have an Object[] in the console log...

Comment: I don't know why .map is broke... But the alternative way works

Comment: Ok Great, I don't like so must the alternative because If the API doesn't exactly the same data at the same place of your domain model. I think it's work